# Write variable shortcut

Tags: c#, asp.net, text, render

I have the following code:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="<%= GlobalVar.BasePath %>/css/style.css" />
```

the c# code is rendered as text, but the following works:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href=<%= "\"" + GlobalVar.BasePath %>/css/style.css" />
```

Just curious, what is the solution to render it normally like I did in the first example?

I just want to know why it renders as text.

Comment: Could you paste what is rendered in each case?

Comment: This question can be linked to this :[http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5603086/problem-in-expression-tag-to-bind-string-variable][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5603086/problem-in-expression-tag-to-bind-string-variable

Comment: Please don't prefix your titles with "C# ASP.NET" and such. That's what the tags are for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure why you're getting the issues, but you could solve the problem of using the GlobalVar by programmatically adding the css link:

```
protected void Page_Init(object sender, EventArgs e)
{ 
    HtmlLink css = new HtmlLink();
    css.Href = String.Format("{0}/css/style.css", GlobalVar.BasePath);
    css.Attributes["rel"] = "stylesheet";
    css.Attributes["type"] = "text/css";
    css.Attributes["media"] = "all";
    Page.Header.Controls.Add(css); 
}
```