# Dynamic query string in html css link

Tags: c#, html, asp.net

Can anyone tell me why this works:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="/js/jqFuncs.js?v=<%=jqFuncsScriptlastWriteTime %>" />
```

But this doesn't

```
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="/css/site.css?v=<%=sitecsslastWriteTime %>" />
```

My code behind has:

```
public string jqFuncsScriptlastWriteTime = System.IO.File.GetLastWriteTime(@"c:/web/cs3/js/jqFuncs.js").ToString("yyMMdd");
public string sitecsslastWriteTime = System.IO.File.GetLastWriteTime(@"c:/web/cs3/css/site.css").ToString("yyMMdd");
```

The rendered HTML looks like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="/js/jqFuncs.js?v=131126" ></script>
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="/css/site.css?v=&lt;%=sitecsslastWriteTime %>" />
```

Comment: could you try adding rel="stylesheet" on your link tag?  not sure if it is required in all browsers.  According to this, it is required: http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_link.asp

Comment: the rel doesn't make a difference to the server rending the variable

Comment: So this is a server side problem -- the variable is not written into the page?  You should update your question instead of saying "it doesn't work".  If it is not writing the expected variable value into the page on the server side, I would guess the file c:/web/cs3/css/site.css doesn't exist or you don't have access to it.

Comment: What is your generated source @GordonCopestake ?

Comment: Fair point David, updated question with html output

Comment: Great, now we can fix this for you!  Please refer to this for fix: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5603086/problem-in-expression-tag-to-bind-string-variable

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is caused by the way ASP.NET treats LINK tags.  Here is another question/answer that provides the solution:

[Problem in Expression tag to bind string variable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5603086/problem-in-expression-tag-to-bind-string-variable)

I would try adding runat="server" first on the link tag.  If that does not work, then I would use the other solution that is the accepted answer.

Comment: Thanks Dave, this pointed me to a slightly different answer, but one that worked!

Comment: NP - I found the link valuable because it had the REASON why your original code did not work as well as a solution!  Happy coding!

Answer (score 2):

Hie Gordon,

There are some differences between `href` and `src`. More details here:

[Difference between SRC and HREF](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3395359/difference-between-src-and-href)

Thanks!

Comment: hmmmmm i see. Is there a way I can add a dynamic query string to a href then?

Answer (score 2):

For anyone else searching for the answer i used this:

```
<%= String.Format("<link type=\"text/css\" rel=\"stylesheet\" href=\"/css/site.css?v={0}\" />", sitecsslastWriteTime) %>
```